# MySQL - adding join changes count/sum values?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions

I can't help thinking this is a common question but for the life of me I can't find a solution.

Say I have this query:

```
SELECT
    ue.user,
    SUM(w.times) AS total_watches,
    COUNT(w.vid_id) AS total_unique_watches,
FROM users ue
LEFT JOIN watches w ON w.user_id = ue.user
WHERE ue.user = "fv9jgpd1cmo" && ue.user_type IN ("ds", "s")
GROUP BY ue.user
```

That works fine. It pulls out users, plus the number of times they've watched any video, plus the number of unique videos they've watched. The values are correct - I've checked.

If I then extend the query with another join, however:

```
SELECT
    ue.user,
    SUM(w.times) AS total_watches,
    COUNT(w.vid_id) AS total_unique_watches,
    COUNT(DISTINCT m.linked_vid_evt) AS answered_vid_events
FROM users ue
LEFT JOIN watches w ON w.user_id = ue.user
LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.from_uid = ue.user /* <-- new join */
WHERE ue.user = "fv9jgpd1cmo" && ue.user_type IN ("ds", "s")
GROUP BY ue.user
```

...the earlier `COUNT`/`SUM` stats are now way off (in this example, `total_watches` should be 40, and then jumps to 880.)

What am I doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure it's something to do with `GROUP BY`, and I've tried adding columns to that, but I can't seem to crack this.

Comment: Undoubtedly the new join creates more records (one to many relationship). To solve it, you can use a subquery to count linked_vid_evt per from_uid, before joining back to outer query

Comment: Interesting... if you can elaborate on that in an answer I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It uses a subquery computing the `count` first. The `distinct` may be unnecessary in this solution as well.

```
SELECT
    ue.user,
    SUM(w.times) AS total_watches,
    COUNT(w.vid_id) AS total_unique_watches,
    m.answered_vid_events
FROM users ue
LEFT JOIN watches w ON w.user_id = ue.user
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT from_uid, COUNT(DISTINCT linked_vid_evt) answered_vid_events
   FROM messages
   GROUP BY from_uid 
) m ON m.from_uid = ue.user
WHERE ue.user = "fv9jgpd1cmo" && ue.user_type IN ("ds", "s")
GROUP BY ue.user
```

Comment: Thanks - worked a treat. How come I don't have to do this for the first join, on watches? Is it only subsequent joins after the first?

Comment: @Utkanos since one row of `watches` has just one user it is ok. but when you join with `messages`, then one row of `watches` may have many corresponding `messages` (via `users`) and via versa. Therefore, `watches` or `messages` aggregation has to be in the subquery (or possibly both).